# Widget doesn't respect ID parameter

Tags: java, android

I have multiple layouts using the same button id which in this case is @+id/button1, at runtime i inflate the layouts and grab each button individually from their given views. The first button grabs just fine but all subsequent buttons of the same given ID cannot be found using findViewById (called from the owned view not activity).

Examining the button in the debugger shows the subsequent buttons have nearly the same ID tag but incremented by 1. It seems Android is not respecting the IDs given by the XML file if there pre-exist an instance of the ID.. Is this the case? If so how can one bind the buttons across views, do we need to give every widget a globally unique ID?

Comment: I don't know what happened but deleting the layout and rebuilding it again seems to have solved the problem. Though the original issue was real, I stepped through the debugger many times over. Something is happening with the resources and how they are being compiled for Android projects resulting in mismatched IDs for widgets between the XML file and deployed resources.

Answer (score 2):

Every widget that exists **in the same view hierarchy at the same time** should have a unique ID value.  In other words, you are more than welcome to reuse `@+id/button1` in your application layouts, but inflating multiple views into the same hierarchy with the same ID could cause ambiguity.

It depends somewhat on how your actual layout(s) is/are constructed, but another thing you can do to resolve some ambiguity is call findViewById() from a different view further down the hierarchy.  For example, I can create a single layout like so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_one"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Row One"/>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_two"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Row Two"/>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row_three"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Row Three"/>
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Notice how all the buttons have the same ID value.  In order to get references to these buttons, I can't just call `findViewById()` from my Activity...which one would I get??  However, `findViewById()` can be called from any View, so I can do the following to get references to each button:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.row_one).findViewById(R.id.button);
Button two = (Button)findViewById(R.id.row_two).findViewById(R.id.button);
Button three = (Button)findViewById(R.id.row_three).findViewById(R.id.button);
```

And now I have a reference to each unique button, even though they had the same ID.  Having said that I still don't advocate doing this if your application matches the example.  Creating unique ID references helps keep the code readable as well.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Devunwired, I do call findViewById() per view vs activity. I'm managing my views manually and doing custom transition between them so at startup I inflate and bind the buttons. That's why it was so perplexing why Android wasn't respecting the ids, as thats a critical part of my scheme ( I'd rather not uniquely name each button for the entire project ).

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, each button gets its own `static final int` which we can call unique ID, right?

Yes, you should give each button it's own ID... And you shouldn't name buttons `button1`, `button2` and so on.